# Facebook Graph not retrieves email address

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I use Facebook login for website currently it doesn't retrieves email address I have update to Facebook Graph API endpoint version from v9.0 to v11.0 also I requested for both email and  public_profile permissions in App Review section like below image but it still retrieve just (id,name,first_name,last_name ) and email is empty here is the VB.NET code to handle the Facebook Graph API

```
 Public Sub GetUserData(ByVal FacebookAppId As String, ByVal FacebookAppSecret As String, ByVal RedirectURL As String, ByVal Code As String)
    
    Dim targetUri As Uri = New Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=" & FacebookAppId & "&client_secret=" & FacebookAppSecret & "&redirect_uri=" & RedirectURL & "&code=" & Code)
    Dim at As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim str As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(at.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim token As String = str.ReadToEnd().ToString().Replace("access_token=", "")
    Dim combined As String() = token.Split(""""c)
    Dim accessToken As String = combined(3)
     
    Dim url As String = "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name&access_token=" & accessToken.Trim(""""c) & ""
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Method = "GET"
    Dim userInfo As StreamReader = New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim jsonResponse As String = String.Empty
    jsonResponse = userInfo.ReadToEnd()
    Dim sr As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim jsondata As String = jsonResponse
    Dim converted As FacebookUserData = sr.Deserialize(Of FacebookUserData)(jsondata)

    userId = converted.id
    userName = converted.name
    userFirstName = converted.first_name
    userLastName = converted.last_name
    userEmail = converted.email



End Sub
```

[Permissions and Features image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4xbt.jpg)

Here is the login button

```
Protected Sub btnFBSignIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFBSignIn.Click


    Dim fbAppId As String = "AppID"
    Dim fbUrllRedirect = "https://mywebsite.com/Login"
    Dim fbApiUrl As String = "https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth/?client_id=" & fbAppId & "&redirect_uri=" & fbUrllRedirect & "&response_type=code&state=1"
    Response.Redirect(fbApiUrl)




End Sub
```

Comment: And where exactly do you think you are _asking_ the user for the permission? I don’t see any `scope` being passed in your login button code.

Comment: I have no idea how to add scope in the login URL could you show me a way

Comment: You need to add a `scope` parameter to the login dialog URL, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login

Comment: @CBroe I have added the scope in the login button code it was worked for me.
 thanks